# Please help me find out why i am in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

this is a bisection root method

```
double p1::root(double (*pf)(double k), int a, int b, double e) {

  // void nrerror(char error_text[]);

  double left = (double)a;
  double right = (double)b;
  double midpoint;

  do
  {
      midpoint = ((right+left)/2);

      if(pf(left) *pf(midpoint) <0){
          right = midpoint;
      }
      else if(pf(right) * pf(midpoint) <0){
          left = midpoint;
      }
      else{
          break;
      }
  }while(abs(right-left) >2*e && abs(left-right)>e);

  return midpoint;
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `pf`, `a`, `b`, and `e`?

Comment: While this isn't your problem, your while comparison is a bit redundant - using only abs(right-left)>2*e does the trick

Comment: Are you passing in a `pf` function that has an infinite loop?

Comment: Can you post the code to the `pf()` you're using when you have the infinite loop?

Comment: abs(right-left) >2*e && abs(left-right)>e is a bit redundant.

Comment: @user570098: With this code, passing a value of zero for `e` can cause an infinite loop. See @sehe's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting some printfs in an doing some tracing  of where you are.

Comment: why not pick up a debugger while you're at it

Comment: +1 for tracing where you are. -0.5 for suggesting `printf` in a C++ answer. Rounded up for good karma `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple *exclusive relationals* `<`, `<` and `>`

I expect at least one of them to **be *inclusive* (`>=` or `<=`)**

This is a good general rule of thumb (exceptions may occur, e.g. with intermediate increments of the compared values... so you need to stay awake, which is the first goot rule of thumb)

Comment: The purpose of the first two `<`s is to check for negative numbers, so `<=` would not make sense. The `>`s in the while loop (one of which is redundant, as pointed out by KWV) are used to check for an error threshold, so `>` makes sense *as long as `e` is not zero*

Comment: Which, now that I think about it, is probably what went wrong `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Compile the program giving a `-g` switch for debugging and run it by [gdb](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/). That way you will know for what values is your `do-while` condition becoming true erroneously.